# Причинное значение оборотов с как: новые веяния?

Tags: пунктуация

В учебниках Н.Н. Соловьевой нашла такие рассуждения.

"*Отцу, как заместителю директора, пришлось ехать в министерство* (это сравнительный оборот, не предполагающий равенства значений: отец не заместитель директора, но может справляться с его функциями).

*Отцу как заместителю директора пришлось ехать в министерство* + *Моя рекомендация сработала как лучшее средство* (приложение имеет значение причины, что можно проверить подстановкой союза *потому что* или предложно-падежной формой *в качестве*: потому что он директор, в качестве лучшего средства)".

Получается, что причинное значение не выделяется запятыми, потому что служит критерием различения приложения и сравнительного оборота. Кто-нибудь в курсе: это личное мнение автора или одна из официальных научных позиций?

Comment: >причинное значение не выделяется запятыми, потому что служит критерием различения приложения и сравнительного оборота
  
Я не вижу здесь оснований для такого вывода.
Да, отчасти наличие обособления можно рассматривать как критерий для различения приложения и сравнительного оборота.    
Но это что-то вроде побочного полезного продукта, **причина** совсем не в том. Сравнительный оборот по своей сути обычно более обособлен, даже интоначионно, и пунктуация только отражает этот факт.

Answer (score 4):

Тема обособления оборотов с союзом КАК является сложной, а ее освещение во всех учебниках желает оставлять лучшего. В частности, абсолютно игнорируется интонационный метод пунктуации, да и семантический рассматривается весьма приблизительно.

Вот несколько замечаний по теме. Во-первых, следует различать обороты со значением тождества и сравнительные обороты, я бы их обозначила так: "а = в" и "а как в". Решение задачи в каждом случае разное. Во-вторых, предложение должно быть построено (автором) таким образом, чтобы его можно было обособить, если автор хочет его обособить (то есть мы должны иметь определенную интонационную структуру).

Приведу похожий пример:

(1) Я пришёл сюда как честный человек, чтобы раскрыть вам глаза. Здесь я не хочу обособлять оборот, делаю его центром высказывания, придаю ему значение "в качестве, в роли". Дело не в том, что я - честный человек, а в том, что здесь требуется любой честный человек, в том числе и я подойду.  Оборот тесно связан со сказуемым.
(2) Я, как честный человек, намерен сдержать данное мною слово. Это обособленное приложение со значением причины, аналог придаточного предложения: я сдержу слово, так как я честный человек.

Разберем приведенный пример:
Отцу, как заместителю директора, пришлось ехать в министерство. Это оборот со значением тождества (не сравнительный оборот). Структура предложения такова, что я однозначно СЧИТЫВАЮ с нее, что отец - заместитель директора, и именно поэтому он поехал в министерство, так как заместителей директоров, как и самих директоров, туда приглашали. Дело в том, что в такой позиции оборот обособляется в ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНОМ порядке, а обособленный оборот имеет значение причины.

Если автор хочет вложить сюда ДРУГОЙ СМЫСЛ, то предложение нужно перестраивать: Вместо директора, в министерство пришлось ехать отцу как его заместителю.

Из всего сказанного следует одно: точный смысл СОДЕРЖАНИЯ передает его ФОРМА (грамматика и  структура предложения), а знаки пунктуации должны ей просто СООТВЕТСТВОВАТЬ, так как все это должно быть заложено уже в УСТНОМ варианте сообщения. А все веяния и официальные позиции всегда будут выглядеть как нечто искусственное в живой материи языка.

Answer (score 0):

Странное обоснование у Соловьевой. Может кто-то поспорит со мной? Но здесь ведь никакого сравнения нет????? Слова "как заместителю директора" в данном случае выступают в значении "в качестве", поэтому запятой не отделяются. Отцу в качестве заместителя директора пришлось ехать в министерство. Хотя без контекста сложно судить. Возможно, там имеется в виду то, что отец, будто заместитель директора, вынужден ехать в министерство.  Тогда запятая нужна, но, по-моему, проще не создавать таких двусмысленностей.

Comment: Если с обособлением, то Ваша трактовка неправильно.
Отцу, как [какому-то мелкму] заместителю директора, пришлось ехать в министерство [на такси]...  
  
А о чем спорить желаете?