# Это модное "на переулке"

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Отовсюду сейчас слышишь "**на** переулке" вместо *"**в** переулке".* Например *на Благовещенском.* Что это — новая норма или надо не позволять этому укореняться по мере возможности?

Comment: В темном переулке, где гуляют урки, Мурка окровавлена лежит.

Answer (score 3):

1. Форму «на переулке» можно отнести **к сленговой  (молодежной) грамматике.** А сленг – это словотворчество, а не коверкание языка, этим он и привлекателен. Главное в нем – отход от обыденности, игра, ирония, маска. Здесь создается особый мир – гибкий, подвижный, наполненный новыми красками, и он противопоставлен миру взрослых, где всё **постоянно, однозначно и немыслимо скучно**.
2. Можно ли сказать «на переулке»? **Что нам посоветует Грамота.ру?** Нет, конечно, нет! Литературной норме соответствует вариант «в переулке», предлог «на» в этом случае  не употребляется. Сочетаемость предлогов с существительными обусловлена **традицией** (в переулке – на улице). Видимо, дело в том, что переулок больше связан с представлением **об ограниченном пространстве**.
3. Соблюдение традиций, безусловно, важно. Улица – это  обширная территория,  скверы, бульвары, а  переулок – всего лишь узкое пространство,  стиснутое каменными громадами  домов. Но ведь кроме физического пространства, существует еще **пространство ментальное**, а оно, как в фантастическом романе, имеет свою **особую размерность;** оно наполнено эмоциями, идеями, связано с разными событиями, с интересными людьми, а для каждого человека – это его собственная жизнь, которую он вовсе не намерен считать ограниченной.
4. **Как, например, Высоцкий.**

Где твои семнадцать лет?

**На Большом Каретном.**

Где твои семнадцать бед?

На Большом Каретном.

И где не гаснет ночью свет?

На Большом Каретном.

А где тебя сегодня нет?

На Большом Каретном.

Помнишь ли, товарищ, этот дом?

Нет, не забываешь ты о нём.

Я скажу, что тот полжизни потерял,

Кто **в Большом Каретном** не бывал.

Итак, вы можете побывать **в Большом Каретном**, но всё другое – только **на Большом Каретном.**

5. **Кстати, предлог «на» использовали и раньше,** так что в данном случае  сленговая форма может оказаться хорошо забытой старой. Поэтому давайте послушаем некоторые [высказывания](https://pishu-pravilno.livejournal.com/4706220.html):

Я выросла в Москве, в пору моего детства вообще чаще говорили «на», например, на скверике. И жила я на Лялином, а не в Лялином переулке.

Я тоже выросла в Москве, и старый корпус нашего института называли «на Подсосенском».

Я из Подмосковья и живу «на Новом», хотя Новый – это переулок. Но при этом машина, например, стоит в переулке.

6. **Поэтому не стоит делать поспешных вводов.** Пусть даже в данном случае мы имеем своеобразную  «протестную» грамматику,  акт непослушания, но он несет в себе определенную **информацию**. Не следует **привыкать к застывшим формам,** как и к незыблемым истинам, даже если они кажутся нам таковыми. Исключения для них всегда найдутся.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Язык развивается при использовании ненормированных форм – пусть это будет не игра, а творческая мастерская. Если есть потребность в разной семантике, которую выражают предлоги В и НА, то эти варианты придется когда-нибудь нормировать. А "играть" только по правилам Грамоты.ру тоже большого интереса нет, они дальше своих "формуляров" не смотрят.

Добавлю несколько примеров из литературы (это уже не сленг):

Это было уже **на переулке Ильича**, уже в Ленинграде, в той самой квартире, где Вася снял комнату. [Т. В. Доронина. Дневник актрисы (1996-1997)].
**На переулке Сивцев Вражек** есть несколько монументальных правительственных зданий без вывесок. [Василий Аксенов. Таинственная страсть (2007)].
Мы пришли в отделение милиции **на переулке Крылова** рядом с Публичной библиотекой [М. В. Куценогий. Прописка // «Волга», 2014].

Форма "в переулке" чаще используется без названия, например: Я ходила на уроки к ней домой (**она жила на Рождественке, в переулке**, который выходил к зданию Архитектурного института [И. К. Архипова. (1996)]  **Кафе находилось недалеко от Арбата, в переулке.** [Н. Б. Черных. 2015]

И еще немного о переулках. "В Москве до середины XX века переулок был самым распространённым адресным объектом. В начале XIX века в городе было 142 улицы и 518 переулков, а в начале XX — 404 улицы и 936 переулков и проездов[5]. Название переулок в XX веке стало устаревать. Новые переулки в Москве теперь называют либо проездами, либо улицами".

Да, действительно, переулки в Москве часто не отличаются от улиц, поднимаются до их уровня. Но дело не в этом, здесь важна традиция **языковой сочетаемости слов**. Надо на слух освоить сочетания с предлогом НА.  Поэтому не стоит во всех случаях использовать один вариант (только НА или только В), такие крайности нежелательны.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, Sharon! Мне не нравится, что с В вообще перестали употреблять и с НА уже не игра, а единственный встречающийся вариант.

Answer (score 2):

Не хотел сначала лезть в эти разборки... Но пришлось.

Я не буду долго и нудно заниматься морализаторством на тему правил, просто обозначу, что из всех названий типов улиц (от переулка до проспекта) только два самых мелких требуют предлога "в" - тупик и переулок (проезд еще, но тут вариативно) . Шоссе, бульвары, проспекты, - все на.
Об этот факт разбивается вся патетика, по которой "НА" - ошибка и/или сленг.
Просто, видимо, "переулок" поднимается до уровня улицы (каковой, собственно и является, историческое понимание переулка как отрезка проезжей части "от улицы до улицы" давно устарело).

Что касается Высоцкого и "Большого Каретного", то тут, пожалуй, есть тонкость, которая мне, как коренному москвичу, понятна. Речь идет о районе, а не о самом переулке.
Не знаю уж, насколько это понятно жителям других городов, но старшее поколение москвичей должно меня понять. Я вижу определенную семантическую разницу в конструкциях "на Арбате" и "в Арбате", "на Столешниковом" (знаменитый некогда магазин пирожных) и "в Столешниковом", "на Проезде Художественного театра" (МХАТ тогдашний и МХТ нынешний) и "в проезде".
Короче, я не думаю, что это явление, с которым нужно бороться. Обычные для языка колебания в/на - а там посмотрим, куда вывезет.

Comment: Сразу не понял: почему разборки? И разве надо обосабливать "как коренному москвичу"?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ в любом случае! А когда вообще употребляется "в Арбате"? Если что-то называется "Арбат", тогда понимаю.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой *И разве надо обосабливать "как коренному москвичу"?* - согласен, похоже, что не не надо. Но очень хочется. )))  Понимаете, я вижу здесь причинное значение,  а этот момент не формализован. Вот, чтоб далеко не ходить https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/31698

Comment: *А когда вообще употребляется "в Арбате"?* - боюсь, что сейчас уже нигде. Это всего более воспоминания из детства. Надо Гиляровского перечитать, может оттуда. Но у меня сил нет сейчас на это.

Comment: *Разборки* - ну, возможно, я слишком резко выразился, будучи в плохом настроении ))). Я имел в виду обсуждения на уровне "я так считаю" + комментарий про Мурку, ибо аргументов серьезных тут привести невозможно.

Comment: (+) Вспомнил. ***"На Сивцевом Вражке"***. Вот уж ни разу не слышал "В Сивцевом..."

Comment: Интересно про "как..."! Убедили) Про Сивцев Вражек тоже очень интересно!)

Answer (score 1):

Второй ответ

Мне хотелось бы подвести итог дискуссии (то есть свой собственные итог). В первом ответе  я много говорила о семантике и мало о форме, поэтому **форме** сейчас уделю особое внимание.

1. **Сначала про «разборки», как я их понимаю.**

Меня этот термин не удивил, потому что я сама бралась за вопрос с некоторым опасением, даже немного подстраховала себя. Дело в том, что всегда  надо с осторожностью обсуждать **три темы: религию, ударение и предлоги На и В**, в силу их особого воздействия **на эмоции людей**. Это я знаю по себе. Вот в погожий денек выходишь на улицу, чувствуешь, что жизнь прекрасна, а ты любишь всех и вся. Но стоит услышать слово с вариативным  (неправильным!) произношением, как непроизвольно превращаешься в существо из каменного века: шерсть искрит, а спина выгибается.

2. Если говорить о переулках и районах, то можно выделить **три формы**. В первом случае предлог **непосредственно** управляет нарицательным словом: ***я живу на переулке, а сейчас поедем в Арбат*** (имеется в виду район). Это, конечно, **сленг** – игра, протест, вызов  обществу  и получение подростками удовольствия от неправильного сочетания.  Такое явление вряд ли укоренится, скорее переулки исчезнут. Потому что **к сочетаемости рядом стоящих слов** язык относится очень ревниво – вот если на расстоянии, то ничего, можно.
3. Если  переулок и предлог **разделены названием** (именем собственным, особенно если сложным именем), то появляются варианты, в том числе  зависящие от глагола.   Цитирую форум с обсуждением предлогов:  И жила я ***«на Лялином переулке», а не «в Лялином переулке».*** Здесь можно услышать сочетание  «жить в переулке», которое  не всем нравится, поэтому использован предлог НА, но предлог В в принципе тоже возможен. Это уже традиционный выбор.
4. Третий вариант – это **не называть переулок вообще**:  «…к примеру, близкие соседи обитали в Подсосенском или в Казарменном (слово  «переулок» просто не указывалось)».   Не называть переулок  – это (в данном случае) способ избежать нежелательного сочетания.
5. Таким образом, выбор предлога зависит  и от семантики, и от самого сочетания (от управляющего глагола) – **от многого зависит**. И уж конечно, этот выбор реально существует. Поэтому надо иметь хороший слух и давать оценку каждому **конкретному** случаю,  а не сводить все к общему правилу или к неприятию ситуации в целом. Именно в  этом я вижу культуру языка  и поэтому  выступаю против всякой однозначности и нетерпимости.

Comment: Спасибо! Нравится последний пункт. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю, что это новообразование возникло в разговорной речи. Подобную конструкцию можно услышать и в сегодня часто встречающемся, действительно модном "у нас на районе".

Comment: Спасибо, Виктор! Вопрос в том ещё, как к этому относиться.

Comment: Плохо относиться, Тёмыч.

Comment: Хорошо, так и буду, Галина.)) Впрочем, я так и делал.))